# Google News website - block particular subjects?

Tags: google-news

Is there any way to block a single subject in Google News?
Thinking Covid-19 in particular.
Can't find any way to block this subject on the Google News website.
I know Google News mobile apps do allow you for such things but can't see similar functionality on the website itself.